# Issue with preferences on my samsung tablet but not my phone, possibly context related?

Tags: android, sharedpreferences, android-context, samsung-mobile

I have an app that works fine on my phone (Huawei Mate 10 Pro) but I have issues on my tablet (Samsung Galaxy Tab S2). I have previously posted a different question regarding issues on one and not the other, but this issue is completely separate.

I use a preference screen to save some settings. One of these settings (a unique id) is only shown but can be copied by clicking it, otherwise it is only handled by the app itself. Everything works just as it should on my phone, but some parts of the code seems to not work on my tablet (the value is empty there). Since the code is identical something must be handled differently between the devices. I'm not sure, but could it be the context?

Several code snippets to follow.

From my PrefFregment, works on both devices:

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.app_settings);
    getPreferenceScreen().getSharedPreferences().registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(this);

    getPreferenceScreen().findPreference("UID").setOnPreferenceClickListener(new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
            Context context = preference.getContext();
            SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);
            String uid = prefs.getString("UID", "");
            uid = uid.trim();
            ClipboardManager clipboardManager = (android.content.ClipboardManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
            ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("UID",uid);
            clipboardManager.setPrimaryClip(clip);
            Toast.makeText(context,R.string.UIDtoast, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Another snippet from my PrefFragment, works on my phone but not the tablet:

```
private void updatePreference(Preference preference) {
        preference.setSummary(PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(preference.getContext()).getString(preference.getKey(),""));          
    }
```

The last snippet, it's from my main activity. It works on my phone but uid is empty on my the tablet:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
String uid = prefs.getString("UID", "");
uid = uid.trim();
```

Comment: dont use "this" in PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);

Comment: Ok, so what should I use?

Comment: get the context

Comment: could you be more specific? that snippet is from my main activity, so I couldn't get the context from the preference right? how do I make sure they have the same context?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue. I had been wrong all along regarding the underlying problem. The context worked fine just as it was. The issue was that I at an earlier point had changed the preference in question from a editTextPreference to just a Preference, and thus its text couldn't just be edited. I had to enter the uid value through an editor instead. Then everything worked. The reason some of it worked anyway was that the previous value was still stored in the preference since before the change. I noticed this when I reinstalled the whole app and suddenly all values were empty. I still don't know why there was a difference between the devices. But now the issue itself is solved at least.